# How do I get amazon price information into Google Sheets?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

In the old version of Google spreadsheets, this could be done with the following formula:

```
=value(importXml("http://www.amazon.com/<your url here>", "//b[@class='priceLarge']"))
```

However, in the new version of Google spreadsheets, this does not work

How is this to be done now?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

=importxml(hyperlink(concatenate("AMAZON_URL_HERE")),"//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the , by a ; to make it work:
`=importxml(hyperlink(concatenate("AMAZON_URL_HERE"));"//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")`

You can also specify the element, like this: 
`=importXml("AMAZON_URL_HERE";"//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")`

The Syntax is explained here:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: This is not working for me