# Amazon price in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I tried following the answers gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679966/how-do-i-get-amazon-price-information-into-google-docs), but I get the error `Imported Xml content can not be parsed`.

Here's what I tried:

`=importXml("http://www.amazon.it/Asus-GeForce-Scheda-Display-Edition/dp/B00SKWIISQ/","//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")`

`=importxml(hyperlink(concatenate("http://www.amazon.it/Asus-GeForce-Scheda-Display-Edition/dp/B00SKWIISQ/")),"//*[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")`

None of them worked..

**EDIT:** The functions are intermittently working. Seems there's an issue specifically with the Amazon site as sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't (and I get "imported content cannot be parsed"). When it doesn't, sometimes if I add or remove the trailing slash it works again. No problem with other sites. Seems a known issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/UuMGRl7Asew https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/yWPaNDK0Kpg
What's a mistery is the cause.

Answer (score 2):

if you try `//*` xPath, then you'll see that Amazon is making a robot check. That is the reason of unsuccessful parsing.

Unfortunately, I can't see the obvious way to overcome this.

And, as to changing comma to semicolon and vice versa - it doesn't work, because it depends on your local settings for Google Spreadheet, which delimiter you have to use in functions. For some countries it's a comma, for others it's a semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=importXml("http://www.amazon.it/Asus-GeForce-Scheda-Display-Edition/dp/B00SKWIISQ";"//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']")
```

I changed the colon to semicolon and removed the trailing slash of the URL to make sure that no HTTP redirects are done.

Comment: Nope.. I still get "Imported Xml content can not be parsed"

Comment: What locale do you have in Settings?

Comment: I use Swedish as locale.

Comment: See here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E9fer--hX22dVRSaPf-4Fj274OrBVMw9oL0wLi0pjcE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Actually.. it's not solved as that wasn't the problem. Seems there's an issue specifically with the Amazon site as sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't (and I get "imported content cannot be parsed"). When it doesn't, sometimes if I add or remove the trailing slash it works again. No problem with other sites. Seems a known issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/UuMGRl7Asew https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/yWPaNDK0Kpg
What's a mistery is the cause.

Comment: @Pafjo - Can this still be used? I've been trying and no dice.